# Where do we find Azure SQL Sync in the new Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Since the old Portal states that SQL is only managable through the new Azure Portal from April onwards, the new Azure Portal however doesnt seem to support the Azure SQL Sync Options. Where or when will these be available?

Answer (score 2):

Just like you mentioned, it will be available in new portal starting April 3rd this year (2017). Until then you should use classic portal for SQL Sync. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync (especially comments).